# how do you make Scite interactive?

Tags: input, ide, command-prompt, scite

Once I compile with Scite, my command prompt won't show up.
How do I set it up so I can accept inputs and outputs from the command prompt from my program using Scite?

Answer (score 0):

In scite properties file Edit as below:

Change

```
 command.go.*.c=$(FileName)
```

to

```
command.go.*.c=start $(FileName)
```

Pressing go opens the tatget file in new cmd window and is now interactable
Now you can give inputs

If you are using different language replace  ***.c**  with corrosponding one and put **start** before the command.